# Was my answer "appropriate"?

Tags: discussion

I posted an answer: [How should I position the letters in a square logo to read “H S S C”?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/41285/15476).

It was mentioned in a comment that my answer was not appropriate.

I just wanted to make sure that I'm contributing to the site in a way that fits the rules.

Was my answer "appropriate" for the site and for this question ?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Has two upvotes which means the community tends to agree

Comment: @ZachSaucier - Actually 4-upvotes, and 2-downvotes (net +2). But, I'm not focused on the downvotes, I was more looking at the "negative" comment. Of course negative votes and comments will always be expected from time to time.

Answer (score 5):

It was my comment.

The user specifically was asking how to position the letters so they read correctly. He wasn't asking how to redesign the piece.

I felt the users deciding they should design it *for* him were going too far.

If you look at the other answers, they all address the question "How does this read?" and "How can I improve the order in which the initials are read?"

I'm sure *everyone* could have redesigned the piece for better legibility, but that wasn't the question.

If someone asks "Which of *these* blues should I use here?" and a user answers, "use red!" it's just as off the mark.

It's fine to add your own spin. In this case a redesign. However, the actual question being asked still should be answered.

Only my opinion.

Comment: I'll second this because I agree with it and often find myself thinking this exact same. Especially when I'm the one asking the Question on some other StackExchange. It bothers me when I ask X or Y and someone chimes in with paragraphs and paragraphs about Z. I feel bad because they're trying to help, but I downvote them anyways for the reason Scott mentions.

Answer (score 2):

> Was my answer "appropriate" for the site and for this question ?

Personally, I wouldn't have down-voted the answer, though I didn't upvote the answer either for that reason but I do understand where Scott is coming from.  I would encourage you to possibly meet Scott's valid comment and edit your question to actually answer the question and then include your current answer as suggestive feedback which could always be helpful to the OP and an option the OP could take.  Down-voted answers can be reversed by the downvotee and when an edit has been completed and the purpose of them are to encourage better, quality, and accurate answers.  To me, if you came back and actually answered the question I would imagine the down-voters would remove them and upvote but I can only speak for myself so that is what I do.